# Retrieving hash from Ransack generated URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Rails 5.0.2 application with Ruby 2.4.3.

When I filter with Ransack I got an URL similar to:

```
http://localhost:3000/clients?q[address_name_cont]=test&q[address_country_code_cont]=US
```

When I first run the search, in the controller's params I will have:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"q"=><ActionController::Parameters {"address_name_cont"=>"test", "address_country_code_cont"=>"US"} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"clients", "action"=>"index", "locale"=>"en"} permitted: false>
```

Is it a simple way to recreate the search hash from URL and identify the attributes?

Yes, I can parse it and create a hash, but I'm looking for something that it consider all predicates and help me to retrieve only the model's attributes used in search.

Comment: dont you have everything in params[:q] ?

Comment: I tested again and they are. But, what about retrieving the attributes names. Is there something that I can use from Ransack?